# Calculate the hash of files with Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, bouncycastle

I'm looking at Bouncy Castle to see how the performance of its hash algorithms compare to that of the .NET Framework, and it doesn't look too great; the MD5 implementation is around 6x slower than .NET's, and the SHA256 implementation is around 3x slower than .NET's.

So I want to make sure I'm using Bouncy Castle correctly, since the documentation is virtually non-existent. Here's what I'm doing:

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests;

public byte[] Hash(string filename)
{
  IDigest hash = new Sha256Digest();

  byte[] result = new byte[hash.GetDigestSize()];

  using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, 
    FileShare.Delete | FileShare.ReadWrite))
  {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4092];
    int bytesRead;

    while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
      hash.BlockUpdate(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    hash.DoFinal(result, 0);
  }

  return result;
}
```

***EDIT***

For comparison, here's how I'm doing it with .NET:

```
public byte[] Hash(string filename)
{
  byte[] hashBytes;
  HashAlgorithm hash = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();

  using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, 
    FileShare.Delete | FileShare.ReadWrite))
  {
    try
    {
      hashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(fs);
    }
    finally
    {
      hash.Clear();
    }
  }

  return hashBytes;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code that you're comparing it with to get the "around 6x slower" and "around 3x slower" numbers?  Are your results matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible that the two algorithms are so vastly different that you experience a differential of 3-6x, it is also likely that the issue is a result of an I/O difference.  By passing in a FileStream to the .NET implementation, it is possible that it is doing some clever things internally to achieve better I/O performance (such as hashing and reading concurrently) that you are not doing in your Bouncy Castle example.

To test this you can either:

1. Make your two examples as similar as possible (this is what I would do).  You can use TransformBlock and TransformFinalBlock in the .NET HashAlgorithm that will be more similar to your Bouncy Castle test.
2. Try to make I/O optimizations to your Bouncy Castle code and see if you can approach the performance of the .NET implementation.

This may be moot though.  If the .NET implementation meets your needs, it may be the best fit for your application.  It seems that it may already have some performance characteristics built in that you would have to add manually to the Bouncy Castles implementation.

Comment: Tried 64K buffer (65536 bytes), made no real difference

Comment: @Cocowalla You could also try using TransformBlock and TransformFinalBlock in the .NET implementations to make your tests more similar.  That would tell you if the underlying hash algorithms performed similarly.  If those results come out close, then it is most likely an I/O difference.

Comment: I tried that, and the .NET implementation actually performed about another 6% faster - so it looks pretty conclusive that the Bouncy Castle implementation is just much slower than .NET's

Comment: @Cocowalla Excellent - that sounds like a solid result.  Good to know too.  :)

Comment: FYI I have done something very similar and didn't use filestreams. I had to push the buffer up to 16mb to get the best performance. Perhaps try increasing your buffer more.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you should check is whether you're IO-bound or CPU-bound. If you're CPU-bound, then I suspect that *is* Bouncy Castle. If you're IO-bound, it could be that .NET is being smarter about the IO. To start with, you might want to increase your buffer size from 4K to (say) 64K. Just give it a try. That's a really easy change. A harder change would be to use async IO so that you're reading the next buffer's-worth of unhashed data while you're hashing the data you've already got.

Comment: Bouncy Castle version only uses ~12% CPU, which I guess suggests it is IO bound - but increasing the buffer size made no discernible difference

Comment: @Cocowalla: 12% CPU *on an 8 processor box* is basically processor-bound. Do you have 8 processors, or 4+hyperthreading?

Comment: I hadn't though about it like that - yes, it's a quad-core with hyperthreading (so, 8 'logical processors). Just checked, and CPU usage peaks the same at ~12% with all of the algorithms I'm looking at

Comment: @Cocowalla: In that case it sounds like it's just a matter of Bouncy Castle being less efficient, I'm afraid :(

Comment: Thanks for your help with this - I'd accept both answers if I could, but Luke's was a bit more specific in allowing me to nail it down. You'll have to make do with an upvote ;)

Comment: In general Java is not very fast when it comes to cryptographic operations when directly implemented in byte code. That said, I've seen faster implementations than those in Bouncy. You are better off using a native function that fully utilizes the CPU (e.g. vector instructions) though. I'm a big fan of Java but it is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

1. Seems like you're using it correctly.

   - If you're not sure, Test your code by comparing the hashes with .NET
     hashes.
   - You can also test *different block sizes* and see if they
     improve your code's performance. 4092 might not be the optimal size
     for larger streams. Also, try take a block sizes which are multiples of 2.
2. You're also right about the performance differences between both implementations. 
   My latest testing presented the Bouncy Castle MD5 hashing on c# nuget is ~X2 slower than the .NET hashing.

[image: MD5 hashing times (milliseconds)]

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this question is quite old, but currently I'm able to obtain the same speed for both .NET and Bouncy Castle's MD5 algorithm implementation.

However, instead of computing the hash while reading the file, I'm reading the full file contet in a previous step and then hashing it:

```
    var md5Digest = new MD5Digest();
    var hash = new byte[md5Digest.GetDigestSize()];

    md5Digest.BlockUpdate(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    md5Digest.DoFinal(hash, 0);

    // Once used, mark buffer content to be garbage collected.
    buffer = null;
```

(I'm plenty aware that storing the full file content in memory may not be very convenient).

Comment: Good to know BouncyCastle's performance has improved over the past 7 years ;)